# Is it possible to call a REST API from Power BI to create a realtime feed?

Tags: powerbi, appdynamics

I'm trying to create a live connection from our AppDynamics data to PowerBI for reporting purposes. An example of a command I would need to run to get AppD data is below.

```
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer <AUTH_TOKEN>" "http://master-onprem-controller.e2e.appd-test.com:8090/controller/rest/applications"
```

Is it possible to run arbitrary commands like this in PowerBI to return JSON data to PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

just to make it clear, a `live connection` is (in the world of Power BI ) a connection to either a Power BI dataset or a SSAS tabular model.
I think what you are looking for is `DirectQuery`, but it is currently not supported for URL GET commands.
[MS docs - Power BI data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources)

To get realtime data you need to use one of the supported sources. maybe AppDynamics supports direct DB access. DirectQuery is supported by SQL databases.
Another way is to offload the data to a supported source eg. SQL-db or CDS-service and then connect your pbi to that source.